# Flow (React Native) is giving me errors for using 'this.state'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

Flow is giving me the following error whenever I try to use `this.state` in my code:

> object literal: 
>   This type is incompatible with
>   undefined. Did you forget to declare type parameter `State` of identifier `Component`?:

Here is the offending code (though it happens elsewhere too):

```
class ExpandingCell extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isExpanded: false
    };
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated =)

Comment: can you post the the other functions?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to define a type for the state property in order to use it.

```
class ComponentA extends Component {
    state: {
        isExpanded: Boolean
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isExpanded: false
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: That is indeed the answer, thanks! I am still unclear as to why the app was working despite this error...

Comment: The reason the app was working despite the error is because the app don't need it. Flow needs it to be able to do type checking correctly but not the actual app.

Comment: It sure would be great if i could get flow to ignore that error then =)

Comment: @MichaelCampsall You can always disable flow altogether. It's a static type checker which helps you write expressive code, but it's totally optional for any kind of JS project (not only React Native).

Comment: Rishat's edit on 23 Dec means that this answer now has invalid syntax. Someone with privileges please roll back. Type annotations in Flow use ':' – it should be `state: {      isExpanded: Boolean;    };`

Comment: giving me error on flow version 0.61.0, it wasn't before.

Comment: This does not eliminate the flow error anymore, so there must have been some change.  The Derek Soike solution eliminates the flow error.

Answer (score 30):

If you're using *flow* and want to set `this.state` in your component's `constructor`:

---

**1.** Create a `type` for `this.state`

```
type State = { width: number, height: number }
```

**2.** Initialize your component with that `type`

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State> { ... }
```

**3.** Now you can set `this.state` without any *flow* errors

```
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { width: 0, height: 0 }
  }
```

---

Here's a more complete example that updates `this.state` with the width and height of the component when `onLayout` is called.

```
// @flow

import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View} from 'react-native'

type Props = {
  someNumber: number,
  someBool: boolean,
  someFxn: () => any,
}

type State = {
  width: number,
  height: number,
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    }
  }

  render() {

    const onLayout = (event) => {
      const {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        width: width,
        width: height,
      })
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayout}>

        ...

      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})
```

Comment: How to utilize the type definition of `Props`?

Comment: This works, but I don't know why it's necessary to pass in Props as a type.  The three properties in Props aren't actually used in the code sample.  However, if I eliminate the Props type, this code then does not eliminate the flow error referenced in the original post.

Comment: This worked for whereas the older answer on this question did NOT.

Comment: @amoldbird ..would u able to find out the explanation ??

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the state with flow type `:any`, but this is not recommended. You will get lost when your state get bigger and more complicated.

```
class ExpandingCell extends Component {

    state: any;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isExpanded: false
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -23):

delete the `/* @flow */` in you code flite top

Comment: More context should have been provided including possible options... i.e. rectify the flow setup or disable if not needed.