# Cannot set flow types to react state

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I created a react component and set flow types according to this answer: [Flow (React Native) is giving me errors for using 'this.state'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860349/flow-react-native-is-giving-me-errors-for-using-this-state). But it still gives an error: `object literal this type is incompatible with object type`

My code:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: ''
    };
  }

  state: {
    email: String;
  };
}
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: what error are you getting? `object literal. This type is incompatible with this.state = object type` ?

Comment: @QoP Sorry my mistake. The error is `object literal this type is incompatible with object type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `string` instead of `String`. [They are not the same](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-strings).

> Remember that string and String are different types.
>
> A string is a literal value like "foo" or the result of an expression
>   like "" + 42.
>
> A String is a wrapper object created by the global
>   String(x) constructor.

this

```
state: {
    email: String;
};
```

should be

```
state: {
    email: string;
};
```

So your component should look like this

```
class Login extends Component {
  state: {
    email: string;
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: ''
    };
  }  
}
```