# Flow giving error while setting state in constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I am trying to use Flow in with my react code, but i am not able to solve this 1 error.
Here is my code

```js
type State = {
  showClearSearchButton: Boolean,
  location: String
};

class XYZ extends Component<State> {
  constructor (props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showClearSearchButton: false, (this line throws error)
      location: '' (this line throws error)
    };
  }
}
```

The above 2 lines throws error `Flow: object-literal. This type is incompatible with undefined`

I am not able to find a solution, tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860349/flow-react-native-is-giving-me-errors-for-using-this-state) method also but doesn't work. Please anyone can help?

Comment: You need to define the props (1st param) as well - Component<*, State> for example.

Comment: @OriDrori Yes it worked, but i also needed to change `Boolean` to `boolean` and `String` to `string` in `type` then it works fine. Why is that can you explain?

Comment: Because the names of the base types in flow are lowercase.

Comment: Thanks @OriDrori